# the dynamic would surely be altered

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does **"the dynamic would surely be altered"** mean in the following context?

> If I wish, I may effectively restart the pilgrimage into the unknown,
>   though, with no necessary end in sight this time, the dynamic would
>   surely be altered. Turning back, on the other hand, would in the
>   meantime be going over old ground.

Answer (score 1):

From this definition,

***dynamic***

> - A characteristic or manner of an interaction; a behavior.
>     [wiktionary.com](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dynamic)

it could be read as the behaviors and interactions which characterized the situation being reflected upon.

Answer (score 0):

In this sense, the "dynamic" is a synonym of **impetus** (a moving force; impulse; stimulus) and is related to positive trend/context that motivates the author.

If the dynamic is altered (negatively changed), the uthor will draw a smaller benefit from restarting the pilgrimage.